# ASP Classic For each loop

Tags: asp-classic

Is **For each loop** can be use in asp classic

and if so, how to loop through all **controls** of the page??

Comment: Have you considered using ASP.NET instead, form your set of recent questions it may be more suited to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP there is no such thing as a "Control".  ASP is a script where all the content outside of `<% %>` and `<script runat="server">` blocks is treatedsimply as a set of bytes to send to the response at that point in the script execution.

The defacto script language of ASP is VBScript and that does have a `For Each` statement that allows the enumaration of collections however you won't find a colllection of controls in ASP.

Comment: Sorry if this is too old, but is there equivalent `For Each` statement for `ASP javascipt`?